# I want splash screen in android12 but i have errors from sdk version

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, splash-screen

CompileSdk, targetSdk used 32.
Then, to use SplashScreen API migration, i have to use sdk 31.
this,
**build.gradle(:app)**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
```

So I lowered the sdk version to 31,
but there was an error.(4 issues were found when checking AAR metadata)

```
4 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-31.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
      of at least 32, for example 33.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  2.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-31.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
      of at least 32, for example 33.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  3.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-31.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
      of at least 32, for example 33.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  4.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-31.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
      of at least 32, for example 33.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Rx
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"

    // Splash screen
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'

    // Kakao login
    implementation "com.kakao.sdk:v2-user-rx:2.11.2"
}
```

This is my dependencies and I changed 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0' to 1.4.0.
But it still does not work.
What should I do? please..

Thank you for reading my question. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does tell you how to fix it in this very line :

```
Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
of at least 32, for example 33.
```

So in your build.grade(:app) instead of this :
[image]

Simply do change it to this :
[image]

It should work fine and make sure to upgrade your all dependencies

Comment: You don't have to update `targetSdkVersion` though (like it says in the error logs) and often you wouldn't want to! Just changing the compile SDK version should be fine

Comment: @cactustictacs you are actually right, I misread the error's message, The funny part is I already encountered this problem like 1000 times, Just a bad habit I do when I see this error I change both

Comment: Yeah it can be a good reminder to do it, but there are a lot of behaviour changes with each version, so it's better to update `targetSdkVersion` mindfully and with a plan - unless you're just in the early stages of an app and you're not even thinking about that stuff yet! Then you might as well go for the most recent API, if you don't have a reason not to

Comment: @cactustictacs True